# Database query to check if current user has created a node reference?

Tags: database, nodes

I have a content type B with a node reference field (from url) pointing to content type A. 
When current user is at "node/add/typeB/nid_of_type A" page then how can i check the database if he has already created a B node for that A node?

I am trying the following code in my template php:

```
function theme_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'b_node_form') {
global $user;
if (arg(0) == 'node') {
 $nid = arg(3);
}
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
->condition('type', 'b', '=')
->condition('uid', $user->uid, '=');
$query->join('field_data_field_a_ref', 'ar', 'n.nid = ar.entity_id');
//field_a_ref is the node reference field from B to A type
$query->condition('field_a_ref_nid', $nid, '=');
$query->groupBy('ar.entity_id')->execute();
if(!empty($query)) {
drupal_goto('/');

    } else {

   }
  }
 }
```

But i get this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM node n INNER JOIN field_data_field_a_ref ar ON n.nid = ar.entity_id W' at line 1: SELECT FROM {node} n INNER JOIN {field_data_field_a_ref} ar ON n.nid = ar.entity_id WHERE (type = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND (uid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) AND (field_a_ref_nid = :db_condition_placeholder_2) GROUP BY ar.entity_id; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => vote [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => 1 [:db_condition_placeholder_2] => 7 ) in theme_name_form_alter() (line 109 of C:...\sites\all\themes\theme_name\template.php).

Any help?

Comment: Could you pop the exception you're getting in as well? Are you using the References modules or the Entity Reference module for your node reference?

Comment: Hi Clive. I added the error in my question. I'm using Refrences and Node reference from url widget modules to achieve this.

Comment: Check the answer I've put in, that should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a while to spot this, but you're not selecting any fields in the query so the SQL syntax here `SELECT FROM {node} n` is invalid.

Just select a field and you should be fine:

```
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid'))
  ->condition('type', 'b', '=')
  ->condition('uid', $user->uid, '=');
```

Comment: Thanks Clive now it finally works nice with no errors! But i must have some other mistake at my code because the query never returns empty. It always returns as if current user has already created a B node. I'll look in to it. Please give it a check also. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Probably because you're just testing `if ($query)`; `$query` will be an object either way so that statement will always return true. Try assigning the result and actually pulling a field out to determine existence, e.g. `$result = $query->groupBy('ar.entity_id')->execute()->fetchField(); if ($result) { ....`

Comment: Ok everything working perfect. You were right. Thanks!